# The UIKeyboard doesn't dismiss as it should

Tags: objective-c, ios

I don't know why my keyboard doesn't dismiss when a textfield has finished to be edited. This is the content of the textfield delegate. (I've implemented both method just for testing purposes):

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO; //I've also tried YES
}
```

Both method are correctly invoked but the keyboard remains active. Why ?
Thanks

Comment: did you set the delegate of the textField to the controller?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the two methods in the question wouldn't be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the `textFieldShouldReturn` should return YES.

Second, make sure the UITextField's delegate is the file's owner

If you use interface builder, you can do it with control drag

or

if you create it from code, than in`viewDidLoad` you must have the following line `[yourTextField setDelegate:self];`

Comment: First point: In the code you can see Ive added the comment, ive tried both YES and NO. Second point: It it set, otherwise the methods in my question, wouldnt be invoked

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

I was having the same issue last night and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Is this an iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad, or combination of devices specific issue? What type of view is your textfield on? UIView, UIView with UIViewController, etc.?

Comment: It is an iPad. An UITextField. An UIViewController with xib file containing the view and such fields.